# specific index of a json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

How do I make an array of 3 selected elements of a json object
so far:
Json object returned from mysql, php into an array of arrays 
tested true as array

```
var json = $.parseJSON(data);
$(json).each(function(i,val)
{
 $.each(val,function(k,v)
{
 console.log(k+" : "+ v);
```

console displays

0 : 2013-03-28 20:18:05

1 : THE MURC THEATRE

2 : COMEDY

3 : -37.001732

4 : 174.789467

5 : -36.998543

6 : 174.787339

7 : 47

8 : 1

9 : 9

10 : 0.00

11 : 1.00

0 : 2013-03-28 20:18:05

1 : DOWNTOWN THEATRE

2 : DRAMA etc etc

Assuming php gave these numbers as keys, when i try to reference them using alert (data.'3'[4]); or alert (data.3[4]); I get unexpected number/unexpected string errors.
I just want the 1st 3rd and 4th items from each iteration to be stored in a variable, how do I reference this ?

Comment: Thanks guys ! Works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data.'3'[4]` and `data.3[4]` are both invalid JavaScript syntax.  The correct syntax is still `data[3][4]` (or perhaps more accurately `data["3"][4]`.  You can use bracket notation to access object members even if the keys are numeric.

Comment: Confusingly enough `obj[1]` and `obj['1']` wil give you the same results (I think because it uses string keys so it `.toString`s anything you pass in bracket notation).

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with a multidimensional array structure:

```
data[x][y]
```

Replace `x` and `y` with desired indexes.